# Global list object being treated as int

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have defined some list object outside of a class as below,

```
time_offset=[datetime.datetime(2018,9,25,9,15,0)]*len(symbol_list)
volume_offset=[0]*len(symbol_list)
timer_var=[datetime.datetime.now()]*len(symbol_list)
green_status=[0]*len(symbol_list)
```

I have the below method written in a class.

```
def updateWindow(self,stock,price_type):
        global time_offset
        global pass_if
        global green_status
        global red_status
        global green_count
        global red_count
        idx=int(company_index_pair[stock])
        if (datetime.datetime.now().minute)%5==0 and price_type==11 and pass_if[idx]==True:
            pass_if[idx]=False
            time_offset[idx]=datetime.datetime.now()
            volume_offset[idx]=volume_list[idx]
        if (datetime.datetime.now().minute)%5==1:
            pass_if[idx]=True
        time_fraction=(1+(datetime.datetime.now()-time_offset[idx]).seconds)/300
        #avg vol for stock to be retrieved from excel file
        change=(volume_list[idx]-volume_offset[idx])/(time_fraction*float(average_vol[stock]))
        dvalues[idx].set(round(change,2))
        entries[idx].config(textvariable=dvalues[idx])
        if change>6.0:
            labels2[idx].config(bg="blue")
        elif change>2.0:
            labels2[idx].config(bg="orange")
        else:
            labels2[idx].config(bg=mycolor)
        avg1=(fifo_list[idx][0]+fifo_list[idx][1])/2
        avg2=(fifo_list[idx][60]+fifo_list[idx][61])/2
        avg3=(fifo_list[idx][118]+fifo_list[idx][119])/2
        #labels[idx].config(text=fifo_list[idx][119])
        #avg4=(fifo_list[idx][58]+fifo_list[idx][59])/2
        if avg3>avg2>avg1:
            green_status[idx]=1
            green_count[idx]+=1
            clabels[idx].config(text="("+str(green_count[idx]).zfill(3)+")")
            labels[idx].config(bg=green_dark)
            timer_var[idx]=datetime.datetime.now()
        if avg3<avg2<avg1:
            red_status[idx]=1
            red_count[idx]+=1
            clabels[idx].config(text="("+str(red_count[idx]).zfill(3)+")")
            labels[idx].config(bg=red_dark)
            timer_var[idx]=datetime.datetime.now()
        if green_status[idx]==1 and (datetime.datetime.now()-timer_var[idx]).seconds>100:
            labels[idx].config(bg=mycolor)
        elif green_status[idx]==1 and (datetime.datetime.now()-timer_var[idx]).seconds>60:
            labels[idx].config(bg=green_light)
        elif green_status[idx]==1 and (datetime.datetime.now()-timer_var[idx]).seconds>30:
            labels[idx].config(bg=green_medium)
```

I am getting the int object not subcriptable error on the below line (sixth line from botton in the above code),

```
if green_status[idx]==1 and (datetime.datetime.now()-timer_var[idx]).seconds>100:
            labels[idx].config(bg=mycolor)
```

The green_status variable has been defined a list, but somehow it is being treated an int object. The time_offset object and pass_if are defined in a similar way but I am not getting that error for them. Please advise.

Comment: `idx=int(company_index_pair[stock])` The error is because this you made and `int` and `int` s are not subscriptable

Comment: It did not work even when it was idx=company_index_pair[stock], please see my comment to @kosist for more info

Comment: But since green_status is a list and idx is int, shouldn't green_status be subscriptable?

Comment: `print(company_pair[stock])` what value is returned

Comment: yes it would be a single value

Comment: and we should be able to use this single value as an index to a list like green_status, right?

Comment: You should be getting a key error if `green_status[idx]` is the cause a subscriptable error is you trying to iterate tsome that is not iterrable

Comment: comments getting long i cant invite you to chat either

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180709/discussion-between-navkanth-and-vash-the-stampede).

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that this line 
`idx=int(company_index_pair[stock])`
causes issues. Are you sure, that `company_index_pair` and `stock` have proper datatypes?

Comment: company_index_pair is a dictionary which takes a stock name returns an index number. Initially it was just idx=company_index_pair[stock], I converted to int thinking it would fix the problem.

Comment: Try to debug your code in a way, that you'll be sure that variables have datatypes, as you expect.
Just, get type of it like: `print(type(green_status))`, etc. for other variables; and check if they are really of the expected type.

Answer (score 0):

And how are labels defined? Any chance they could be int? Also would be nice to paste the exact error massage when you have such problems :)

Comment: labels is a list of tkinter label widgets, it is unlikely that they are ints. The labels are behaving as expected.